# Views boolean column if user has a specific role

Tags: users, views

I have a standard Drupal installation with Views and Administration Views modules installed.

By default, the Users view has a column Roles with ALL the users roles.

How to include a custom column (to replace the default Roles column) to show if the user has or hasn't a specific role (like a yes/no column)?

Comment: Can you be more clear as there is already a column Roles, and you can also filter by an exposed filter on Role

Comment: Hi Reynolds, I edited the question to be more clear. I don't need (now) to filter rows, only show a yes/no for a specific role.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an out of the box method. Maybe someone else will have a better answer. But what I did for a quick solutions is to add the Views PHP module, then add a PHP field with the following output code:

```
<?php 

  $account = user_load($data->uid);

  $roles = array('YOURROLE', 'ANOTHER ROLE');

  if (count(array_intersect($roles, $account->roles))) {
    print 'Yes';
  }
  else {
    print  'No';
  }

?>
```

It will print yes if any user has either of the two roles.